# How to change Magento admin URL to domainname.com/index.php/customname1/customname2

Tags: magento

There are so many articles talking about how to change Magento Admin Url to a single and different name like domainname.com/index.php/myadmin  but none of them tells me how to change the admin url to a multi-path url like domainname.com/index.php/name1/name2/name3

I tried to change the name in local.xml but it works only for single name. Please help? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is possible. The basic method is to change the front name "admin" to "whatever" in the local.xml to get access to the backend. Based on it, you can probably make some changes of the behavior of the router thanks to a rewrite.

A possible way which works for modules is to do a rewrite but I didn't test on backend module (adminhtml) and it could be not to work for other backend modules or make some trouble. Here is a sample to do in the local.xml, make some tests. Regex in the "from" Tag may work too:

```
<config>
...
    <rewrite>
        <mage_adminhtml>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/whatevermodule/whatevercontroller/whateveraction#]]></from>
            <!--
                - whatevermodule matches the router frontname below
                - whatevercontroller matches the path to your controller Considering the router below,
                "/whatevermodule/whatevercontroller/" will be "translated" to
                "/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php" (?)
            -->
            <to>/admin/catalog_product/index</to>
        </mage_adminhtml>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Diglin. But from my experience is this method still allows everyone to access the admin through normal URL http://domainname.com/index.php/admin ??? Because I don't want them to access the admin through this url. I want to change the path for security purpose.

Comment: You could block it if the referer is not /whatevermodule/whatevercontroller/whateveraction. 
The same idea could be done via htaccess.